# Concatenation in smarty

Tags: smarty

I want to assign the value obtained from the concatenation of these two variables with a string.

```
{assign var="url" value="{$WS_PATH}aircraft_images/{$images[i].image}"}
```

Please let me know how can we do this in smarty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smarty local variable concatenation with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144406/smarty-local-variable-concatenation-with-string)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One of these should work:

```
{assign var="url" value=$WS_PATH|cat:"aircraft_images/"|cat:$images[i].image}
```

Or

```
{assign var="url" value="`$WS_PATH`aircraft_images/`$images[i].image`"}
```

I am not sure if the $images[i].image will be parsed correctly, you may have to {assign} it to another variable first

Comment: Second one is way easier to read and worked (first one didn't)

Comment: I think you dont need to call cat more times, Simple $var|cat:'str1':'str2':....... works for me :)

Answer (score 9):

You've used [`assign`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl) properly.

A simplified example could look like this:

yourphpfile.php:

```
$tpl = new Smarty;
$tpl->assign('var1','Hello');
$tpl->assign('var2','World');
$tpl->display('yourtemplate.tpl');
```

yourtemplate.tpl:

```
...
<body>
{assign var="url" value="{$var1} - and - {$var2}"}
{$url}
</body>
```

...will result to the output:

```
Hello - and - World
```

Comment: This actually works, but where is it documented O.o ?

Comment: @jave.web Have a look at the [variable examples here in the manual](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl), they cover most of the use cases.

Comment: well that hardly shows {} are used to address ambiguities and to concatenate in var/index naming, there is not this case ... x)

Answer (score 5):

such an expression will do the trick:

```
{$product1_photo = "{$smarty.const.IMG_URL}/{$pInfo.PhotoName}"}
```