# Smarty local variable concatenation with string

Tags: php, smarty

How to assign a local template variable with a string concatenated just like below:

```
{$yes_src=const1.'yes'.const2}
```

to be used below in the code in the manner `{$yes_src}`.

By the way I am looking for a job as PHP developer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenation in smarty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023042/concatenation-in-smarty). I like the answers to this one better though.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The way you are doing it is call the "short form" of `assign`, you just need to use the [correct quoting mechanism](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl):

```
 {$yes_src="`$const1`yes`$const2`"}
```

Use `assign`:

```
{assign var="yes_src" val="`$const1`yes`$const2`"}
```

Use `cat`:

```
{$const1|cat:"yes"}{$const2}
```

You can also simply put the variables next to one another without assigning it to a variable:

```
{$const1}yes{$const2}
```

... no variable needed.

**A note**  If you find yourself using `assign` more than **rarely**, you might have a misconception about the ideas of separating logic from presentation. Usually, concatenation and other variable work would be accomplished in PHP before the template is ever involved. The template's role is to *just display the data*, you should avoid creating or altering the data in the template.

**Documentation**

- Smarty quotes - http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl
- Smarty `assign` - http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl
- Smarty `cat` - http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.cat

Comment: Smarty3 also allows {$yes_src = "{$cont1}yes{$const2}"}

Answer (score 14):

```
{ $yes_src = $variable|cat:"some string"|cat:$variable }
```

Comment: Valueable when one need concat string containing quotes because back ticks dos not work with apostrophe.

    {assign 'myLoc' '<span class="my">|cat:{$smarty.config.LOCALE_STR}|cat:"</span>"}

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
{capture assign=yes_src}{$const1}.'yes'.{$const2}{/capture}
```

And then use the new variable:

```
{$yes_src}
```

Comment: This is golden!