# Why doesn't 'text{$variable}' work for me?

Tags: smarty

I'm using the latest stable version of Smarty and can't get this string to work. I've looked at [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11144453) for solution to do this but none seem to work.

This is a template file (TPL), and doesn't contain any PHP at all. Note that the TPL file is compiled to a PHP script and then sent to the browser. It's not a PHP file.

Current code:

```
'foo{$bar}'
```

which outputs as:

```
'foo{$bar}'
```

instead of the value of `$bar`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change it to `"foo{$bar}"`. When using single quotes the string is interpreted literally.

Comment: Is this in a PHP file or in a Smarty TPL file?

Comment: Thanks @gil that solved my problem. But when should double quotes be used compared to single quotes? Want to put it as an answer and explain the difference? (:

Comment: @Alvar : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: @SolarBear but it's not strictly a php problem since this is a TPL file. I know it's compiled into a PHP script but it's not strictly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any variables within text you have to use double-quotes `"` instead of single quotation marks `'`. Text within single quotation marks is not parsed for variables in PHP.

Comment: But this is a TPL file not a PHP file. dot's doesn't work as they do in PHP why should this work then?

Comment: I don't know this tpl-files, just answered in regard to PHP as your question was tagged with php and you didn't say that you aren't using PHP... Sorry

Comment: Is the problem solved now? If this was indeed the issue, I'm not sure what the remaining problem is. Unless the _real_ question is why would `'` and `"` be treated differently in a TPL file?